# Measuring length using 3D Model

Tags: algorithm, 3d, modeling, mesh, measurement

I'm trying to write a program which calculates a length of a plant using 3D model from 3D scanner. Now I'm using Dijkstra'a algorithm but it's finding shortest path form start to end measuring point. Unfortunately length line doesn't always run through the middle of the plant. To do it right I have to make many points on the measuring line.

Does anyone knows any alternative algorithm or how to modify it? I want to give 2 or 3 points and the result is the lenght line running through the middle of the object.

Thats my model of a plant:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c672fhb30xec6sl/wel.JPG?dl=0

Comment: May I ask what these points are and how are they defined?

Comment: it the closest triangle vertex, added by mouse-click. Path is a set of edges calculated with Dijkstra's.